# MediaMetadataRetriever setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFED

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer, mediametadataretriever

I need to fetch frames from video located in the web. That's how I do this:

```
class PlayerWrapper {
    private static final MediaMetadataRetriever mMediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    …

    public void initPlayback(final Context context, final VideoSurfaceView videoSurface, final String url) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                …

                try {
                    mMediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(url, new HashMap<String, String>());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    DPLog(e);
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public Bitmap getFrameAt(int positionMillis) {
        if (mMediaMetadataRetriever != null) {
            DPLog.d("Creating frame for position [%s]", positionMillis);
            try {
                return mMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(positionMillis * 1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                …
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on several devices with Android 4.4, 5 and 6. But on one device with Android 4.1.2 `setDataSource` function fails with following stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFED
       at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever._setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java)
       at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:99)
       at co.unreel.videoapp.playback.UnreelPlayer$3.run(UnreelPlayer.java:138)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Also tried this code on emulator, got almost the same but with status `0x80000000`

Url is got from YouTube API, looks like this:

```
https://r2---sn-n3toxu-axqe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?gcr=ru&sver=3&mm=31&mn=sn-n3toxu-axqe&key=yt6&signature=D1CE7B8615F3D96A58A9D2679057D676E7777E05.5A318AD8C5F48FCED2D1A9149348CD269F466FA9&mt=1456173450&pl=24&mv=m&ms=au&lmt=1455616987173757&itag=22&requiressl=yes&ip=188.242.217.203&source=youtube&dur=848.248&id=o-ABIn_CbRwqIO6qpvlaWe_ekyTZPLVd0w_eM80awd6uRQ&fexp=9408087%2C9416126%2C9419451%2C9420452%2C9421340%2C9422596%2C9423661%2C9423662%2C9425078%2C9425963%2C9427767%2C9427801%2C9428013%2C9428432%2C9428660%2C9429602&mime=video%2Fmp4&upn=P5qxGGbPoc0&sparams=dur%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&expire=1456195127&initcwndbps=3140000&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Why this can happen and what to do?

I also tried to use `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` with the same logic, but it doesn't work at all, `setDataSource` causes exceptions with status `0xFFFFFFFF` on all devices. As I found on SO, that means that url is invalid, but it is ok and played by `MediaPlayer` without any issues. Also I found that ffmpeg has issues with urls longer than 1024, but that's not my case too.

May be there are another way to get frames from video?

Answer (score 0):

Get the same error. **setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFED**

Use Crosswalk on android to play a mp3 file on https server.
And found [this from google source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java)
at line 940

> Sets the data source (file-path or http/rtsp URL) to use.

maybe setDataSource not support https.
and this works when i use http server.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String videoPath = 
    "android.resource://com.example.dvid/"+"/raw/testvid";

Uri data = Uri.parse(videoPath);
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever fmmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
    fmmr.setDataSource(data.toString());
```

I am getting IllegalArgumentException.
I am trying to get frames from a video in Android.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.